# NSView message when being shown and when not?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nsview

Is there some sort of delegate method that sends a message when an NSView is being shown or not? I need to run an NSTimer when the NSView is displayed on the screen and I need to invalidate it when it is not so it doesn't unnecessarily run in the background the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you've implemented your code, you could subclass NSView and create your own delegate protocol that sends out proper messages for various NSView events like [`setHidden`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setHidden%3a) or ["`removeFromSuperview`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/removeFromSuperview).

If you're embedding this view into a single NSWindow object, you could subclass NSWindow and then throw your custom delegate protocol methods for "`close`" or "`performClose:`".  Of course, in this case, there's actually already a ["`NSWindowDelegate`" protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSWindowDelegate) defined for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you perhaps be more specific how I could make use of `setHidden` so that it behaves like a delegate method?

Comment: will your NSView be appearing in only one NSWindow object or could it appear in one of many different unique windows?

Comment: How about detecting when a UITableViewCell is offscreen and then cancelling the timer? [Other people have asked this question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841042/detect-when-uitableviewcell-goes-off-the-screen).

Comment: There is nothing in that post that has helped me. I did find this delegate method `- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex` but I haven't been able to get it work right now. But I need a `willHideCell` version of this.