# The Amount of times a tableviewcell has been viewed and run a function based on it

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I want to fetch the amount of times a cell in a tableview has been viewed when it is completely in the view. That should only happen when it is completely in the view, minor parts of top and bottom cells shouldn't count.

And after a certain amount of time(~3 sec) has passed, it should trigger a function of print "hello".

I tried creating a timer and scheduling it in `willDisplay` method and invalidating it in `didEndDisplayingCell` method. It somehow takes into consideration the cells which are not fully in the view.

Also tried `tableView.visibleCells` and iterating cells in `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows` but nothing helped.

Any Help on this would be much appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you want to keep track of how long a cell is displaying for (and the number of times it's been displayed), you don't actually want to keep these numbers in your custom (subclassed) UITableViewCell, because these cells get recycled and reused very quickly as they are scrolled on and offscreen.

Whatever your datasource object is, you should add a property (or two) to it to keep track of when the object is displayed in a cell (i.e. a "`var displayCount : Int`" property?), and you can start a [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) (or `NSTimer`) to count X seconds before displaying your "Hello" message.

You can detect whether a cell is fully visible via the methods found [in the answers to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible), which is when you can start up your `Timer`.

To detect when the cell is scrolled offscreen (so you can increment the display count and/or cancel the timer), [use the delegate method `didEndDisplayingCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15980777/981049).

Comment: Well, that was exactly what i had tried. But when scrolling through the row, it doesnt refresh the counter, though i have explicitly reset it. It just keep the previous value in the memory and allocates it to the total views.